# Installation of python libraries on OS X

Tags: python, git, numpy, pip, osx-yosemite

When i run the command on terminal 'sudo pip install scipy'(infact with any python package like numpy,pandas..) on OS X yosemite, I get the following error.

```
Collecting scipy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10c566ed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10c599050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10c599190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10c5992d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/scipy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10c599410>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/scipy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for scipy
```

My 'git clone ..' works perfectly fine(I installed home brew). I am behind a proxy and I have done aliasing.

Comment: Tried `conda` http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#anaconda-for-os-x-graphical-install??

Comment: I didn't try that, can't it be done without conda?

Comment: 'Fetching package metadata: Error: Invalid index file:             https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/repodata.json.bz2: Not supported proxy scheme '  this is the error in using conda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify proxy for pip specially,

`sudo pip --proxy http://user:pass@proxy.server:port install packagename`

pip doesn't use the http_proxy variable,set in OS X terminal.

Comment: I have the same issue. What proxy parameter should I pass. Its not clear to me if I should configure this in my mac somewhere.